# no values from jquery in a template to my view function

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am using django and I am getting all id from checkboxes and now I want to pass them to my view function, but I don't know how. I've tried request.GET.getlist('vals') but with no success. any suggestions?

events.html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
        type: 'POST';
            var vals = [];
            $.each($("input[name='checkb']:checked"),function(vals){
                vals.push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
            alert("values: " + vals.join(", "));
        });
    });
</script>

    <td><a href="eprint"><button><i class="bi bi-sim"></i></button></a></th>

    {% for l in object_list %}
      <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id={{l.pk}} name="checkb"></label>
      <form>
...
```

urls.py:

```
   path('eprint',views.eprint,name='eprint'),
```

views.py:

```
def eprint(request):

    print('eprint')
    v=request.GET.getlist(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally solved this problem. I am using AJAX to send the id's to my view:

java script in the template:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
          var vals = [];
      $.each($("input[name='checkb']:checked"), function() {
            vals.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
      console.log('cons2:',vals)
      $.get('eprint/ticked/',{marked: vals}) 
      console.log('after')
        });
    });
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def eprint(request):

    print('eprint')
    print(request.GET)
```