# pushing into a declared list not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to put id values into a list in jquery but I get an error saying that push is not a function. somehow it seems that my list is turned into an object. I am using django. It all worked but suddenly it stopped. why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var vals = [];
    console.log('cons1:', vals)
    console.log('cons1:', typeof(vals))
    $.each($("input[name='checkb']:checked"), function(vals) {
      vals.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    console.log('cons2:', vals)
    alert("values2: " + vals.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' name='checkb' id='check1' />

<button type="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: `$.each(..., function(vals) {` - you've used the same name for the function parameter as outside variable - they're not the same variable.

Comment: Change to `$.each($("input[name='checkb']:checked"), function() {` and it works fine.

Comment: thanks. hard to spot these errors, I come from an emacs scientific background, I am not used to these errors.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  I recommend deleting the question (close as typo) as I'm sure this was just a type/minor mistake and probably won't help anyone in the future.

Comment: yes, maybe it is a good idea to delete it. I have another pending question, how to get the array to my view function, nobody seems to be able to answer that quesation...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872571/no-values-from-jquery-in-a-template-to-my-view-function